# AngularJs animating in directive doesn't work unless i use $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

I can't figure out why the following animation doesn't work as it should:

```
app.directive('openMenu', ['$animate', '$timeout', function($animate, $timeout) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {

                if(elem.is(':animated'))
                    return;

                $timeout(function() {
                    $animate.addClass(elem, 'see');
                }, 0);

            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

And in this one the animation doesn't work at all (and class is not added either):

```
app.directive('openMenu', ['$animate', function($animate) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem) {
            elem.bind('click', function() {

                if(elem.is(':animated'))
                    return;

                $animate.addClass(elem, 'see');

            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

In the second code snippet I only removed `$timeout`, which is 0, I tried to use self-firing functions to check - animating works only when I am using timeouts. Can someone explain me why?

```
middle {
    margin-left: 0;
}
middle.see {
    margin-left: 270px;
}
.middle.see-add {
    -webkit-transition: margin-left 300ms;
    -moz-transition: margin-left 300ms;
    -ms-transition: margin-left 300ms;
    -o-transition: margin-left 300ms;
    transition: margin-left 300ms;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.middle.see-add.see-add-active {
    margin-left: 270px;
}
```

Here is the markup:

```
<div class="middle" open-menu></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your directive uses jQuery and jQuery modify the DOM, we need to tell angular about it. To do so, you need to do $scope.$apply but you would run into the error :  "digest already in progress".

The code executed inside the $timeout guarantee that your code will be safely executed on the next digest cycle.

0 is the default value, you don't even need to specify it. You could simply write :

```
 $timeout(function() {
    $animate.addClass(elem, 'see');
 });
```

The $timeout service is simply a convenient service equivalent to :

```
var timeout = setInterval(function(){
    // do stuff
    $scope.$apply();
}, 0);
```

You can find extensive information about the digest mechanism in the official documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog

Comment: No ` "digest in progress"` error should occur or the version without `$timeout` should have worked?

Comment: Sorry for my poor phrasing. What I meant is that the use of $scope.$apply would have triggered the error "digest already in progress" and that is why he should use $timeout to safely call $scope.$apply

Comment: Yes, I understood that, but I think if that would be the case you wouldn't need any $timeout or $apply callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you happen to be out of the Angular life-cycle. You are using `.bind` so Angular will not be notified whenever something has changed. The `$timeout` works because it's a one of the wrappers to notify Angular about an *outside* change. You could also use `$apply`. Both, the `$timeout` and `$apply` take a callback which will be executed. After the callback is finished Angular starts a `digest` beginning at the `rootScope`. Now every binding will be updated and everything should work properly.

```
scope.$apply(function() {
    $animate.addClass(elem, 'see');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `elem.bind('click')` is a jQuery function, which is running outside of the angular digest phase.

Probably this would work as well instead of using `$timeout`:

```
scope.$apply(function() {
     $animate.addClass(elem, 'see');
})'
```