# AngularJS perform action after $scope.emit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to perform an action after a call to $scope.emit(...) has finished processing  (i.e. all the handlers/listeners have completed), how can I do that?

```
                    $scope.$emit("nsError:setPage", { page: page, ele: ele });// tell page directive to set the current page so that the errored item is visible
                    alert('here');
```

Currently, the alert happens before the UI is updated to the correct page.

Comment: Thanks for having a look GuyT, that's for consuming emitted events (not afterwards as I mentioned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'`$scope.$emit` has finished' is not the same thing as 'UI has updated'. For the UI to be updated, the digest cycle must be complete. You can wait for this to happen by using angular's `$timeout` function (don't forget to inject it in the controller):

```
$timeout(function(){alert('here');});
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  Is that the "correct" way to handle such things?  (it strikes me that if the digest cycle took a long time for some reason, could using a timeout cause timing issues?)

Comment: No, it would no cause a timeout. $timeout is a service provided by Angular. It wraps $apply which wraps $digest. Basically, the code provided by fikkatra ensures that Angular call your code once its ready. I have attempted to explain it here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/33364954/741802

Comment: We're not passing a delay here, we're just using the default delay of 0. What it does, in essence, is to add the alert to the end of the execution queue, rather than process it immediately. This gives the browser time to execute some other stuff, like updating the DOM. You're right to have some doubts about this being the right solution. It does smell funny. Whether or not this is a good way to handle stuff, depends on your specific case, but sometimes it's just necessary to execute code after the DOM has been updated, and in that case, this is the way to go.

Comment: Wonderful explanation (both of you), thank you very much.  +1 for "it does smell funny", captures the sentiment beautifully :-)   Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

If you emit an event:

```
 $scope.$emit("nsError:setPage", { page: page, ele: ele })
```

You could then listen to it :

```
$scope.$on('nsError:setPage', function(event, mass) { alert('here'); });
```

Keep in mind that `$emit` dispatches an event upwards through the scope hierarchy and `$broadcast` dispatches downwards to your child scopes.

More info in the official [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) (scroll to $on)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, see comment for GuyT above - it applies to your answer too, I believe.

Comment: Yep seems like I misunderstood your question

Comment: No worries - followed the link you gave which explained fikkatra's answer, gave you a +1 for that answer. :)